# Mathematic resolution

Tags: algorithm, math

I just heard something very insteresting but cannot find any ressources.
The story is that when faced with an algorithmic problem that requiered multiple ifs, one student of a friend did answer with a mathematic one liner.

Now I already knew that you could do anyting with math but I want to be able to do it.
From what I know it might be possible to do a loop given the shape of those function, but conditions?

Does someone know how to resolve something like:

```
IF boolean
  THEN expression
  ELSE expression2
```

in math terms (without Bool algebra)?

Best regards,

Sarfraz

Comment: You can't really do it in the general case. And the exp/log hack will bite you once you run into limited precision and rounding issues.

Comment: It seems this question is better suited for math.SE. Moderators, can we migrate the question?

Comment: I see, it is true that I did not consider precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `boolean` is either 0 or 1, and expressions are mathematical:

```
expr = boolean * expression + (1-boolean) * expression2
```

Comment: i was just a few seconds slower :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - Your post states "using exponential and logarithms".  Since the accepted answer uses neither of these (but probably is the answer you were looking for), can you please edit your post to more correctly state what you were looking for?

Comment: Done, I removed the exp and log part as It was not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that boolean is 0 or 1:

```
result = boolean*expression+(1-boolean)*expression2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to a [multiplexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)?

If the boolean is S, expression is A and expression2 is B, then the formula for result Z is

[image: Z = (A * S) + (B * ^S)]

Comment: From a quick look it answer the question using boolean equations which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: It is, of course, the same as the accepted answer, except it has a bit more Electrical engineering background.

Comment: Now that you state it, it is correct. I should have deducted the equation from that.